# Como deixar a rolagem do ScrollView sempre visível

Tags: android

Tenho um horizontalScrollView e tava querendo deixar a barra de rolagem sempre a mostra.

```
           <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView2" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/categoria"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                >



            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

tenho este HorizontalScrollView ai coloco imagens dentro dele

```
imageButton.setImageBitmap(bMap);
imageButton.setId(Integer.parseInt(categorias.get(i).id));
layoutC.addView(imageButton);
```

funciona normalmente quando ultrapassa o limite da tela so arrastar que da pra vê as outas imagens , mais tava querendo que ficasse mostrar a barra de rolagem , tipo que fica no navegador

Comment: Só tens barra de rolangem se o que tiveres dentro ultrapassar os limites da mesma no ecrã.

Comment: mais ela não fica aparecendo mesmo se passou o limite

Comment: Coloca ai o teu código para podermos ver o que se passa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No arquivo XML, acrescente o código `android:fadeScrollbars="false"`